# MariaDB / MySQL client table-formatting like `psql`?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, client

I hate to nitpick over style, but for the purposes of use Database Administrators is there a way to clean this up a bit,

```
SELECT 1 AS "myCol1", 2 AS "myCol2";
+--------+--------+
| myCol1 | myCol2 |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      2 |
+--------+--------+
```

For comparison, with PostgreSQL,

```
SELECT 1 AS "myCol1", 2 AS "myCol2";
 myCol1 | myCol2 
--------+--------
      1 |      2
```

Can I get the psql output from MySQL or MariaDB?

I know `psql, the client for PostgreSQL has a ton of options for [formatting the output table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

- `\C` Sets the title of any tables being printed as the result of a query or unset any such title. This command is equivalent to \pset title title. (The name of this command derives from “caption”, as it was previously only used to set the caption in an HTML table.)
- `\a` If the current table output format is unaligned, it is switched to aligned. If it is not unaligned, it is set to unaligned. This command is kept for backwards compatibility. See \pset for a more general solution.
- `\pset`,

  - `border`
  - `columns`
  - `expanded`
  - `fieldsep`
  - `fieldsep_zero`
  - `footer`
  - `format` (supports `html`, `asciidoc`, `latex`, `latex-longtable`, and `troff-ms`)
  - `linestyle`
  - `null`
  - `numericlocale`
  - `recordsep`
  - `recordsep_zero`
  - `tableattr`
  - `title`
  - `tuples_only`
  - `unicode_border_linestyle`, `unicode_column_linestyle`, `unicode_header_linestyle`
  - and on, and on.

Comment: [pspg](https://github.com/okbob/pspg) might be an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no, but there are a few options which may help

- `--skip-column-names`, `-N`Do not write column names in results.
- `--skip-line-numbers`, `-L` Do not write line numbers for errors. Useful when you want to compare result files that include error messages.
- `--silent`, `-s` **Silent mode.** Produce less output. This option can be given multiple times to produce less and less output. This option results in nontabular output format and escaping of special characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see the description for the --raw option.

May be worth nothing that while silent is almost nice,

```
SELECT 1 AS "myCol1", 2 AS "myCol2";
myCol1  myCol2
1       2
```

You're actually losing the tabulated display and just getting a `\t`.

```
SELECT 10000000000000 AS "myCol1", 2 AS "myCol2";
myCol1  myCol2
10000000000000  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You always can get any desired formatting with `sed` batch editor:

```
mysql -t -e 'SELECT * FROM table;' | sed -E '1d;$d;s/^[|+]//;s/[|+]$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the standard `mysql` command-line client that comes with MariaDB and MySQL, try `usql`, the universal command-line interface. From the README file:

> usql provides a simple way to work with SQL and NoSQL databases via a
>   command-line inspired by PostgreSQL's psql. usql supports most of the
>   core psql features, such as variables, backticks, and commands and has
>   additional features that psql does not, such as syntax highlighting,
>   context-based completion, and multiple database support.
>
> Database administrators and developers that would prefer to work with
>   a tool like psql with non-PostgreSQL databases, will find usql
>   intuitive, easy-to-use, and a great replacement for the command-line
>   clients/tools for other databases.

Github project at: https://github.com/xo/usql